# The lattice of covectors of an oriented matroid

Tags: matroid-theory, oriented-matroids

Let $M$ be an oriented matroid on the ground set $E$, and let $L(M)$ be its ranked poset of covectors.  By definition, $L(M)$ is a sub-poset of the poset $\{0, \pm 1\}^E$, ordered by putting $0 < \pm 1$, with the rank being the number of nonzero coordinates.  However, I want to consider $L(M)$ as an abstract ranked poset, rather than as a subposet of $\{0, \pm 1\}^E$.

Question 1:  Is the oriented matroid $M$ determined, up to isomorphism, by $L(M)$?

Question 2:  Is there a nice characterization of which ranked posets arise in this way?

Answer (score 4):

This is an answer to question 1 (not the modified version in the comments to Ben's answer).

If you consider only L(M), you have lost all the information the orientation provides (beyond the bare fact that an orientation exists).  Since there can be more than one, non-isomorphic oriented matroid on the same matroid, it can't be possible to reconstruct the oriented matroid from L(M).  (I don't actually have an explicit example of multiple oriented structures on one matroid in mind, but counts of the orientable and oriented matroids imply that there are orientable matroids with more than one orientation starting in rank 3 with 6 points.)

Comment: Thanks!  Looking at Theorem 4.1 of the Richter-Gebert/Ziegler paper to which Benjamin linked on his blog, I see that knowing $M$ is essentially equivalent to knowing both $N$ and the oriented matroid $P$ obtained from $M$ by deleting the distinguished element.  I can't put my finger on a precise statement yet, but I feel as if the passage from $M$ to $P$ involves forgetting much of the orientation data.  As you noted, the passage from $M$ to $L(M)$ also involves forgetting much of the orientation data.  So I hold out some hope that $M$ is determined by $L(M)$ and $N$.

Answer (score 3):

$L(M)$ is a monoid with covector composition and has a unary operation, its negation. Two oriented matroids are isomorphic iff their associated unary monoids are isomorphic, see my blogpost

http://bensteinberg.wordpress.com/2013/08/13/equivalence-or-oriented-matroids-from-a-semigroup-viewpoint/

I would be surprised if you can recover the negation and product from just the order. But I don't have an example.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm very glad to have learned about the Bohne-Dress theorem from your blog post.  I was not aware of this theorem or even of the term "single-element lifting", though this is in fact exactly what I am interested in.  Let me revise my question accordingly....

Comment: Suppose that I know that $M$ is a single-element lifting of an oriented matroid $N$, which comes with an explicit representation.  That is, I am given $N$, a representation of $N$, the poset $L(M)$, and the negation operation, but not the composition operation.  Surely the knowledge of $N$ buys me something.  What more do I need to recover the composition operation on $L(M)$, and therefore $M$ itself?

Comment: I have to put single element liftings back in my brain to give a good answer. I am not an oriented matroid person. I have to think what single element liftings means in monoid terms. In general the poset is just the poset of principal right ideals under reverse inclusion.

Comment: I think if I remember correctly that N is a contraction of M and a fairly big one. So you should get a fair amount of info, but most likely not everything.